# getting invalid json from twitter api

Tags: java, json, twitter

i'm trying to get data from twitter api with java jsoup and json-simple libs

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json")
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
            .header("charset", "utf-8")
            .data("q", q)
            .data("count", "2")
            .data("max_id", currentStartId)
            .ignoreContentType(true)
            .get();
```

Then i'm receiving some json object. But when i try to parse it

```
String response = doc.text();
JSONObject requestObj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(response);
```

i'm getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" Unexpected character (\) at position 3535.
at org.json.simple.parser.Yylex.yylex(Yylex.java:610)
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.nextToken(JSONParser.java:269)
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:118)
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:81)
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:75)
```

in json position 3535

```
"description":""\u0412\u0435\u0434\u043e\u043c\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0438". \u0415\u0436\u0435\u0434\u043d\u0435\u0432\u043d\u0430\u044f \u0434\u0435\u043b\u043e\u0432\u0430\u044f \u0433\u0430\u0437\u0435\u0442\u0430"
```

Comment: Jsoup is really a terrible client for this sort of api call. It is typically used for web scraping, which this is not. Consider using a generic restful client, Apache HttpClient, or even twitter4j.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using Jsoup as its designed for parsing and cleaning HTML pages.  It's unlikely that whatever it spits out is useful Json for you to process.

https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#connect-java.lang.String-

> Use to fetch and parse a HTML page.

As the comment above suggests, you should use Twitter4J instead for this. Or even just process the JSON directly after fetching with URLConnection or OkHttp.